# Rust IDE not detecting Result from error_chain, thinks I'm using the std::result::Result

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I have an `errors.rs` file with `error_chain! {}`, which exports `Result`, `ResultExt`, `Error` and `ErrorKind`.

If I `use self::errors::*`, IntelliJ thinks that I'm using the default `Result` (`std::result::Result`, I think). However, if I explicitly import the types using `use self::errors::{Result, ...}`, everything works out hunky dory.

I can tell because the standard result has two type params, but the `error_chain` one has only one.

In either case, it still compiles.

I'm using the standard Rust IntelliJ plugin, version `0.1.0.1991`.

Help! Does anyone know how to get the plugin to understand what the macro is doing?

Comment: I guess this is what happens when IDEs are forced to roll out their own semantic analysis :/

Comment: Probably you should report a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: Looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/1243) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IntelliJ-Rust plugin uses its own code parser. It allows to leverage all the IntelliJ platform capabilities (like code navigation, formatting, refactoring, inspections, quick documentation, markers and many others) but requires implementing all the language features, which is not a simple task for Rust (you can find a more in-depth discussion of the Rust compiler parser versus IDE parser in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5rhqj0/ide_compiler_has_very_different_requirements_and/)).

Macros expansion is probably the biggest language feature that is not supported by the plugin parser at the moment. That is, the plugin sees this `error_chain!` call, can resolve it to its definition, but doesn't expand it to the actual code and hence doesn't know about the new `Result` struct that shadows the one from stdlib. Unfortunately, in some cases it leads to such false positive error messages.

I've converted this error annotation into an inspection, so in the next plugin version you'll be able to switch it off entirely or for the particular code block. The work on macros expansion is also in progress.

Comment: Looks like this is supported now? https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/pull/2331 I don't see any links in that PR to a description of what it does or does not handle, though.